# Variable transport delay using time after threshold has been reached in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

In Simulink how can I delay the transport block to the exact time of when a certain threshold has been reached?

Basically I have an S-function which switches to an alternate input source, a sine wave, after a certain value has been reached. As soon as the switch occurs I want to start the sine wave. For that I need to delay the wave generation until the switch occurs.

How can I send that time to the Variable transport delay block?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this way:
[image]
you need `Variable Integer Delay` for example. It changes delay to what you need. Calculate needed value of delay you can in `User Defined Function`, route to it your threshold value and current time and all other values you need.

Hope i understood your question correctly!